Google's ML Kit
Hi I want to use google's ML Kit for my SDK offering to my customer. Is it open source? I don't find any license attached to it. Also it is like a black box that goes along with our offerings and uses API call to interact with it. Can that be considered as "Separate work"?

Could you link to it?

Have you tried a basic internet search ?
https://www.google.com/search?q=google+ML+Kit+license
for me it was search result #1

https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms @mar

These terms and conditions doesn't talk anything abour distribution or usage?

My #1 listed search result points to GitHub and says "mlkit is licensed under the
Apache License 2.0". Google provides an individual sorting of the search results depending on your settings, devices and history, but I can't believe that the link to the GitHub page is not within the first 10 results for you.

The ML Kit Terms of Service mention that "When using the ML Kit APIs, you may not reverse engineer or attempt to extract the source code or any related software, except to the extent that this restriction is expressly prohibited by applicable law."
This prohibition on reverse engineering clearly indicates that ML Kit is not open-source.
I didn't see anything in the Terms of Service that forbids using the API with open-source code, so you can use an open-source license for your SDK, but I don't believe you can use a strong-copyleft license like the GPL without including an additional permission to use the ML Kit. Such an additional permission can only be added if you are the copyright holder who decided on using the GPL.
